# Nginx upstream reconfiguration while one is processing request

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

If I call `nginx reload` after updating my config to remove a reverse proxy from my list of upstreams, what happens to the requests that reverse proxy is currently processing,
will they get served to the user without error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine#Stopping_or_Restarting_Nginx

HUP is the signal sent to nginx when you tries to reload config file. Nginx will start new worker processes and gracefully showdown older ones. So yes, the current request is still served without any error.

> HUP   Configuration reload Start the new worker processes with a new
>   configuration Gracefully shutdown the old worker processes